# Astroid Draw Java Program Problems

Tags: java

I'm trying to generate an astroid (Not asteroid) graphic similar to this:
[image: What I want]

This graphic output is generated on a 400x400 `DrawingPanel`. And the math is based on making curves from straight lines. However, I'm having a problem with my `x,y` coordinates. instead of making the astroid, I'm generating this:

[image: What I have]

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class GraphicsProject
{

    //main method
   public static void main (String[]args){
    //Initialize the variable
    //The Window is 400 x 400 pixels in size
    DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel (400,400);
    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
    drawAstroid(g,0,0, 400);
    }

   public static void drawAstroid(Graphics g, int x, int y, int size){ 
       int scale = size/40; 
       int x1, x2,x3, x4, y1, y2, y3, y4;
       y1 = y;
       y2 = y + size;
       y3 = y + 1/2 * size;
       y4 = y + 1/2 * size;

       x1 = x + 1/2 * size;
       x2 = x + 1/2 * size;
       x3 = x + 1/2 * size;
       x4 = x + 1/2 * size;

       for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++ ){
           //Draws Upper Left
           g.drawLine(x4 - scale * i, y4, x1, y1 + scale * i);
           //Draws Upper Right
           g.drawLine(x4 + scale * i, y4, x2, y2 - scale * i);
           //Draws Lower Left
           g.drawLine(x3 - scale * i, y3, x4, y4 + scale * i);
           //Draws Lower Right
           g.drawLine(x3 + scale * i, y3, x2, y2 - scale * i);
        }
    }
}
```

Any insight into how to resolve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Looking at the first image, I don't think you can recreate it with straight lines. It looks more as if it is created using ovals/ellipses, where the two axes (typically called `a` and `b` in ellipses) vary from 0 to 1 and from 1 to 0 respectively. Think of a circle, that is once squeezed to a vertical line, and once to a horizontal line.

Comment: The math is based on concepts from these web sites: http://mathematicsrealm.blogspot.com/2012/07/curves-formed-from-straight-lines.html & https://mathcraft.wonderhowto.com/how-to/create-parabolic-curves-using-straight-lines-0131301/

Comment: yes, and you did a good start to create such a curve. It's just that your first example is not constructed with straight lines. The outer form of it could be re-created by 4 of those pieces that you started to implemented (for each quadrant one), but not the exact form itself, as this is created using ellipses if you look closely.

Comment: My bad. Maybe this example would be better: http://www.matematicasvisuales.com/images/geometry/curves/astroid/astroide02.jpg